# HttpWebRequest multipart form-data

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, multipartform-data

I am trying to submit simple text data to a multipart-form CGI.

The problem is.. I don't know how to format the form data!

In short, my system prepares a string containing the post data, creates a streamwriter using request.GetRequestStream(), and directly writes the post string to that streamwriter. It then goes on to close the streamwriter, and send the request.

I have tried formatting the string as so:"Param1=sometext&param2=sometext", but I get returned the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation Failed.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x002d9] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1425 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00143] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1250
```

Clearly I am formatting the string wrong, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do so properly.

Can someone enlighten me? :)

EDIT, I also tried changing `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` to `request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";`. This had no avail, but I am going to leave it that way.

EDIT: Full code:

```
public static string sendReq (string url, string pdata)//Pdata is the string containing form data
{
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    HttpWebRequest request  = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    CookieCollection jar = new CookieCollection();
    jar.Add(new Cookie("Cookie","Data","Removed","For privacy."));
    jar.Add(new Cookie("Cookie","Data","Removed","For privacy."));
    jar.Add(new Cookie("Cookie","Data","Removed","For privacy."));
    jar.Add(new Cookie("Cookie","Data","Removed","For privacy."));
    jar.Add(new Cookie("Cookie","Data","Removed","For privacy."));
    l("Loading cookie jar onto request");
    CookieContainer cont = new CookieContainer();
    cont.Add(jar);
    request.CookieContainer = cont;
    if (pdata != "")
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
        request.ContentLength = pdata.Length;
        StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(pdata);
        stOut.Close();
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            l("Data was read. ["+count+" bytes]. Encoding to ASCII");
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            l("Appending to full string");
            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The part of code that handles sending the post data:

```
if (pdata != "")
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
        request.ContentLength = pdata.Length;
        StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(pdata);
        stOut.Close();
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting it for me, Codo :D Forgot I could do that. Helps a ton.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Did you set the "Expect" header?

Comment: Sure, let me fetch it real fast...... And no, I did not set the "Expect" header. Whoops..

Comment: Could you post the header fields of the packet that gets submitted before you get the 417 response?

Comment: I could be that the server expects an "Expect" header and your request doesn't include one or vice versa your request has one but the server doesn't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I'm very new to all of this.. What exactly is the "Expect" header, and how should I format it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Obviously, the *HttpWebRequest* adds an *Expect* header by default, which confuses a lot of servers.

**Update**:

An revert to:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

because the current combination of the content type and the data in the body do not match.

Comment: Hey ,thanks for the response. :D That helped to get rid of the error I was getting. Thankyou very much. :)